# Merge tags doublebuffered and double-buffering

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[doublebuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doublebuffered) x179 questions

[double-buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-buffering) x105 questions

I believe the reasoning is quite obvious.

It's hard to say which one is more correct, I would go with <s>[doublebuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doublebuffered) as it has most questions and a non-zero amount of followers</s>. [double-buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-buffering) because it sounds like an actual topic.

Comment: I'd go with [double-buffering]. Sounds & reads better.

Comment: @Mat On second reading I tend to agree with you, sounds like the name of a topic rather than an adjective. Edited in question.

Comment: And I thought one is about using two buffers, while the other one is about buffering double values :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kennytm proposed this way back in 2010, but apparently, it never was synonymized.

[image]

After 9 years, this is completed:

[doublebuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doublebuffered) (x185) is now a synonym of [double-buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-buffering) (x105)