# Merge [buffered], [buffering]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I suggest merging

[buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffered) x 64

and [buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffering) x 385

as they refer to the same thing.

[buffered] has no usage guidance but appears to be used as a synonim for [buffering].

Comment: Look---my "mandatory downvote comment" already appears in the body of the question! How nice!

Comment: Whooops :-P ...

Comment: I thought this merge is obviously needed and would be easily accepted, but it seems it isn't so...

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to know how this works. In order for you to make a request, at least one that anyone will take seriously, you need to do a bit more research than that. Just mentioning the three tags is not enough.

You should include several bits of information:

- What do the tag wikis/excerpts say?
- Are the tags *really* used as synonyms?
- How many questions does each tag have?
- How many questions are tagged with both?
- Has a similar proposal been made in the past? What happened?

  - The answer to this one is yes, but no merge: [Merge tags doublebuffered and double-buffering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313779/merge-tags-doublebuffered-and-double-buffering)